# Send Text to a Port Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, post, port, printing

I recently got a new printer (specifically a HP Photosmart C6380 if that helps) that allows me to send text to port 9100 to print.  Telnetting into it and typing text to print works fine, but I'm wondering if I could make a webpage using HTML and Javascript that can send text directly to it.

I'm currently using the code from the article [Cross Site Printing (pdf),](http://aaron.weaver2.googlepages.com/CrossSitePrinting.pdf) but the downside is that when it prints out it shows the entire POST request and not just the text.

So my question for you is am I able to send just the content of the POST request or strip the unneeded characters using only HTML and Javascript?

Note: The reason why it's limited to HTML and Javascript is because I'm hoping that I can use this on an iPhone or iPod Touch.

**Edit**:  It appears that there's no way to get rid of the HTTP headers, so now my question is can I craft a custom POST request that will minimize on what is sent in the header? For example, can I not send the user agent since the printer doesn't care what the user agent is?

Comment: Why are you opposed to creating a server-side script to handle your request and forward the data to the printer?  It's like a couple lines of perl...

Comment: I want to avoid setting up a server and having a middleman forward the data. This is mainly for my personal use when I'm connected to my home network. I imagine a local webpage with a textarea that I can type in and press submit and it will print.

Comment: Also, I envision downloading this to my iPod Touch using an app like Air Sharing so that I can type up some text and print it, since it lacks that capability.

Comment: But if it's a solution for your home network, what's stopping you from setting up an only locally accessible webserver? Or even writing a basic one yourself - just drop the header (everything before \r\n\r\n), relay the rest to your printer port and send a '204 No Content' to the browser?

Comment: Nothing is stopping me from setting up a server, I just was hoping that I could make something entirely self contained in just HTML and Javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's no way to get rid of the HTTP headers in client-side JavaScript. For that, you need to set up a server-side script which will then make the actual connection to the printer port.

**Edit:** The server-side script won't send a HTTP request to your printer: It should open a new socket and thus can fully controle what gets sent!

Comment: Am I able to create a custom POST request in client side Javascript though to minimize on the amount of unnecessary information printed out?

Comment: Yes, you can send custom requests via XMLHttpRequest (also called AJAX). But there's no need for that: Use a plain old HTML form (with method="POST") and a server-side language of your choice (PHP, ASP.NET, Perl, Python, ...). Afaik all of these can read POST variables and create sockets...

Answer (score 2):

You can HTTP-Request from within JS, so you always have an HTTP-Header, regardless of the port to which you are sending. So the answer is: no.